# UML - can an "include" case have a different actor than base case?

Tags: uml

For example,

I have base use-case "Make file" accosicated to actor x.

"Make file" use-case includes "send file by mail".

Can "send file by mail" associated to actor y?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is: yes, it can.

For example, actor Y could have the 'role' of someone (or a system) sending files by mail, and could therefore be associated with use case 'send file by mail'.